# Apache RewriteRule is not working with single input

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problems with choosing a directory by HTTP hostname.

I have a file structure like this:

```
.
+-- .htaccess
+-- domains
    +-- 123456.a12.whatever.net
    |   +-- .htaccess
    |   +-- ...
    +-- example.org
    |   +-- .htaccess
    |   +-- ...
    +-- subdomain.example.org
        +-- index.html
```

The `.htaccess` file in the root directory looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%2/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%{HTTP_HOST} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%{HTTP_HOST} -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [DPI]
```

Weird thing is that it works for both `123456.a12.whatever.net` and `example.org` but not `subdomain.example.org`. When I try to access it I get 500 Internal Server Error. I am sure that it is a problem with the `.htaccess` as in the `subdomain.example.org` is really only the `index.html`. Also, the error seems to be in the last line.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to these logs. My web-hosting provider charges an extra fee for it.

Comment: Try last line as: `RewriteRule ^(?!domain/)(.*)$ domains/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually simplify it further by using this negative condition rule:

```
RewriteRule !^domains/ domains/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I played with it at the localhost I found out that it starts cycling for some reason. The log says:

```
[core:error] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://subdomain.example.org/
[core:debug] AH00121: r->uri = /domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/favicon.ico, referer: http://subdomain.example.org/
[core:debug] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/domains/subdomain.example.org/favicon.ico, referer: http://subdomain.example.org/
...
[core:debug] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /domains/subdomain.example.org/favicon.ico, referer: http://subdomain.example.org/
[core:debug] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico, referer: http://subdomain.example.org/
```

Even though I don't know why it loops, I found two different solutions.

#### Solution 1 — Fix the `.htaccess`

I think that the most correct solution is [the one @anubhava suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63932336/7289596). Just changing the last line to `RewriteRule !^domains/ domains/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` is enough and I think it is actually more correct.

#### Solution 2 — Make a `.htaccess`

Strangely, another solution is to add `.htaccess` containing the directive `RewriteEngine On` into the `subdomain.example.org`. I think this is the reason why the other domains worked. I don't know the exact reason for this but it works.

Comment: **Solution 1** - `(?!domain/)` - This would presumably need to be `(?!domains/)` (with an `s`)? (In order to avoid a rewrite loop, hence 500 response.) **Solution 2** - "even a blank `.htaccess`" - a completely _blank_ file wouldn't do anything. It would need to contain `RewriteEngine On` (or `Off`) in order to override the parent mod_rewrite directives (thus preventing a rewrite loop). Mod_rewrite is not inherited by default which is why the other two domains (with a `.htaccess` file presumably containing mod_rewrite directives) does not trigger a rewrite loop.